# How to Hold Down Mouse while Key is Pressed?

Tags: autohotkey

I am new to autohotkey and apologize for my lack of programming knowledge, but as stated in the title, I am trying to make it so while I hold down a certain key on my keyboard, the mouse will be held down at a certain location as well.

The problem I am having is that when I release the key on my keyboard (in this case the "up" key), the cursor is still kept down. Here is my code so far:

```
$Up::
Loop{
    if GetKeyState("Up", "P"){
        Click 112, 429, down
    }
    if not GetKeyState("Up", "P"){
        break
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: @lanuk_hahs - you should mark this solved.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code

```
F1::
    if( not GetKeyState("LButton" , "P") )
        Click down
return

F1 Up::Click up
```

Read the documentation. http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/;

Comment: Ha ha, Armin, you wrote the same thing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17048287/autohotkey-how-to-hold-a-mouse-button-while-a-key-is-pressed

Comment: @BGM Please note the asked and edit dates. I updated the answer (which is always preferable) to a more correct version.

Comment: I only meant to point out that you get around. :)  Our fellow OP should mark his thread!